# ASP.NET MVC - Render PartialView with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Earlier today I posted another post where @Darin Dimitrov helped me great, however once again I'm stucked...
My javascript calls the AddWebsite ActionResult which does it job as it should, however the error function in the $.ajax() is always firing since

```
return PartialView(ListPartialView, MapUserToViewModel);
```

isn't valid JSON.

I've come across examples where people use something like

```
RenderPartialViewToString(partialview, model);
```

and throws it into a JSON object... but it's just too "hackish" if you ask me.. isn't there an easier way to accomplish this?

**... And the code:**

// DashboardController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddWebsite(CreateWebsiteViewModel website)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        throw new HttpException(400, "Client-side validation failed.");
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(website.URL))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("URL", "The URL cannot be empty nor contain only whitespaces.");
    }

    using (_session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        _session.Query(new AddWebsite(_contextProvider.GetUserSession.UserId, website.URL));
        _session.Transaction.Commit();
    }

    return PartialView(ListPartialView, MapUserToViewModel);
}
```

// MyJs.js

```
$("#testform").live('submit', function () {

    var test = { URL: $("#URL").val() };

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Dashboard/AddWebsite",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(test),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("TRIG");
                $("#content").html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your particular instance I think the problem is with your javascript code.  You are specifying the `dataType` (which is what the function expects to parse in the response) as `json`.  Based on the Action you posted you should have `html` as the `dataType` and it should solve your problem.  There's nothing wrong with doing that (you don't have to use JSON for everything).

Answer (score 1):

### Simple data

Why are you setting `dataType` and `contentType` in the first place? Since your object `test` is very simple you can just provide it as is and it will be consumed by Asp.net MVC without any problems and you will return your partial view.

### Complex data

If your object would be more complex then you could use a different [jQuery plugin](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html) that will make it possible to send complex JSON objects without strigification.