# Create a view inside a view on submit MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a view with a form, when that form is submitted I want to show another view inside the first view. I have tried with partialview (not sure that is for my purpose?) but I cant get it to work because the model is null (its strongly-typed partialview). But I just want it to be created on the submitbutton and then it should be OK.

So, help my create a view/partialview inside a when submitting my form. Right now I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on the foreach loop in my partial view, but it's not supposed to be created until the form is submitted.

My view:

```
<div class="calcInput">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("ShowDetail", "Calculation"))
                    {
                       <div class="calculateBox">
                            <label for="calcOption">Choose value to calculate:</label>
                            <select form="anFormCalcInput" id="calcOption" title="Choose what value you want to calculate">
                                <option value="anPMT">Payment (PMT)</option>
                                <option value="anI">Interest (I)</option>
                                <option value="anFV">Future value (FV)</option>
                                <option value="anPV">Present value (PV)</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="calculateBox" background-color="#777777">
                            @Html.Label("Present value (PV)")
                            @Html.TextBox("PresentValue")
                            @Html.Label("Future value")
                            @Html.TextBox("FutureValue")
                            @Html.Label("Interest rate")
                            @Html.TextBox("InterestRate") <br />
                            <input type="radio" name="advanceOrArrears" id="inAdvance" value="inAdvance" /> In advance<br />
                            <input type="radio" name="advanceOrArrears" id="inArrears" value="inArrears" /> In arrears
                        </div>
                        <div class="calculateBox">
                            <label for="startDate">Start date:</label>
                            <input type="date" id="anStartDate" name="startdate" title="Choose start date for your calculation" /><br />
                            @Html.Label("Payment frequency")
                            <select form="anFormCalcInput" id="anPmtFreq" title="Choose the payment frequency, for example: Every month">
                                <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
                                <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
                                <option value="Yearly">Yearly</option>
                            </select><br /><br />
                            @Html.Label("No of payment periods")
                            @Html.TextBox("PaymentPeriods")
                            @Html.Label("Date time convention")
                            <select form="anFormCalcInput" id="anDTC" title="Choose your Date time convention">
                                <option value="360360">360/360</option>
                                <option value="365365">365/365</option>
                            </select><br /><br />
                            <input type="submit" id="anCalcBtn" class="calcBtn" name="anSubmitBtn" value="Calculate" title="Calculate your calculation" />
                        </div>
                    }
                    </div>
                    <table cellspacing="0" width="80%">
                    <div class="calcGraph">
                    </div>
                    <div class="calcDetail" id="anCalcDetail">
                    @Html.Partial("ShowDetail") //This is where I want my view/partialview to show up
                    </div>
```

My partialview:

```
@model IEnumerable<CalcFactory.Models.Calculation>

<table cellspacing="0" width="80%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Invoice amount
        </th>
        <th>
            Interest rate
        </th>
        <th>
            Interest amount
        </th>
        <th>
            Amortization
        </th>
        <th>
            Capital balance
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
    </td>
    <td align="center" id="startValue">
    </td>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) { //this is where i get null exception, model is null. But it supposed to be created on submit button...
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceAmount)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InterestRate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InterestAmount)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amortization)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PresentValue)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

My Controller:

```
public class CalculationController : Controller
{
    public PartialViewResult ShowDetail(FormCollection form)
    {
        List<Calculation> cList = new List<Calculation>();
        Calculation calc = new Calculation();
        calc.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(form["startdate"]);
        calc.InvoiceAmount = 2000;
        calc.InterestRate = Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]);
        calc.InterestAmount = (Convert.ToDouble(form["PresentValue"]) * Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]) / 360 * 30);
        calc.Amortization = (2000 - (Convert.ToDouble(form["PresentValue"]) * Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]) / 360 * 30));
        calc.PresentValue = Convert.ToDouble(form["PresentValue"]) - calc.Amortization;
        cList.Add(calc);
        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(form["PaymentPeriods"]); i++)
        {
            Calculation calcBefore = cList.Last();
            calc = new Calculation();
            calc.Date = calcBefore.Date.AddMonths(1);
            calc.InvoiceAmount = 2000;
            calc.InterestRate = Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]);
            calc.InterestAmount = (calcBefore.PresentValue * Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]) / 360 * 30);
            calc.Amortization = (calc.InvoiceAmount - (calcBefore.PresentValue * calc.InterestRate / 360 * 30));
            calc.PresentValue = calcBefore.PresentValue - calc.Amortization;
            cList.Add(calc);
        }
        return PartialView("ShowDetail", cList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of rendering the partial view directly within the Main view, you can make a ajax call to get the partial view and just dump the html inside a empty div  on your main view. You need to pass on any required parameters to then `Action` method(in your case I belive it will be the Payment periods).

Comment: Can you show me in code how that look like?

Comment: I do not have acces to VS right now, but a quick google might help you find ways to make that call. Here is one [stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466597/rendering-a-simple-asp-net-mvc-partialview-using-jquery-ajax-post-call) link which I found. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844477/asp-net-mvc-render-partialview-with-ajax) is one more. Another [example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/rendering-a-partial-view-and-json-data-using-ajax-in-Asp-Net/)

Comment: I will look at it, but does this mean I don't use my Controller and ShowDetail-action?

Comment: This can be achived on submit as well. You just need to be careful while accessing the model properties. If the Model passed on to the Partial View is empty it would throw an exception. For this you can always check if the current model is Null or not in the Main view. I f it is not null invoke the `PartialView("ShowDetail",cList)`

Comment: Hmm..Going home now but will look at this later this evening. I'm very new to AJAX so I will for sure have some problems with this